# How to invert an integer vector ( array ) recursively in C?

Tags: c

This is my code that doesn't work:

```
#define TAM 5

int vec[TAM];
int revvec[TAM] = {0};

void invertir(int vec[], int revvec[], int i)
{
    if ((TAM - 1 - i) == 0) {
        revvec[i] = vec[0];
    }
    else {
        revvec[i] = vec[TAM - 1 - i];
        invertir(vec, revvec, i++);
    }
}
```

It compiles well but it gets stuck when executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a problem in your code :

```
    invertir(vec, revvec, i++);
```

must be

```
    invertir(vec, revvec, ++i); /* or i+1 */
```

else you always give the index 0 to your recurcive calls and you finaly explode the stack

After that correction your code is ok :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAM 5

int vec[TAM]={ 1,2,3,4,5};
int revvec[TAM]={0};

void invertir(int vec[], int revvec[],int i){
  if (((TAM-1)-i)==0) {
    revvec[i]=vec[0];
  }
  else {
    revvec[i]=vec[(TAM-1)-i];
    invertir(vec, revvec,++i); /* or i+1 */
  }
}

int main()
{
  invertir(vec,revvec, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i != TAM; ++i)
    printf("%d ", revvec[i]);
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/d $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra x.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/d $ ./a.out
5 4 3 2 1
```

---

You can also simplify to have :

```
void invertir(int vec[], int revvec[],int i){
  revvec[i]=vec[(TAM-1)-i];

  if ((TAM-1) != i) {
    invertir(vec, revvec, i + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Swordfish yes the increment is local in the OP code, all recuscive calls get the index 0, this is what I say in my answer

Comment: I understand what you are saying in your answer. I just added that it is unnecessary to increment `i`.

Comment: @Swordfish ah yes, can be i+1, I did to be closer to the OP code, I added comment, thank you

Comment: The logic to break the recursion is overcomplicated. Just do `if (i == TAM) return;` and drop the `else`.

Comment: @Swordfish yes, funny, I just did ^^

Answer (score 0):

To not tie the function to the use of `TAM` in the declaration of the arrays but keep it general, pass the arrays length as parameter:

```
#include <stddef.h>  // size_t

void reverse_impl(int const *src, int *dst, size_t length, size_t pos)
{
    if (pos == length)
        return;

    dst[pos] = src[length - pos - 1];
    reverse_impl(src, dst, length, pos + 1);
}

void reverse(int const *src, int *dst, size_t length)
{
    reverse_impl(src, dst, length, 0);
}
```